# Removing and adding multiple proximity alerts

Tags: android, location, locationmanager, proximity

My use case:

-My app has for example 3 lon/lat locations that i fetch from a server. These may change between fetches.
-I want to add proximityalerts for all three, but when i re-fetch the locations i wish to re-create the proximityalerts, in case the lon/lats have changed.

I have seen the methods in locationmanager and have found some examples, but i cannot see a "removeAll" method anywhere, nor have i found a way to do it. All deal with that i have to create the pendingintent, alert and register the receiver for each location, with a unique ID every time...

I had hoped to basically use the same intent/pendingintent for all my proximityalerts, so that when i later call the remove, i only need to call the method once, and all my proximityalerts would be removed, like the code below.

Any tips? Is this totally impossible?

```
//CREATE (i would use the same way to create intent for all my proximity alerts, and have one broadcastreciever that receives all for the intent with that ID):
Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT_ID);
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    lm.addProximityAlert(
        latitude,
        longitude,
        POINT_RADIUS,
        PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION,
        proximityIntent
    );

//REMOVE:
Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT_ID);
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

//i had hoped that this call would remove all alerts at once?
lm.removeProximityAlert(proximityIntent);
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem?

Comment: Afraid not. Looks like you have to keep track of everything yourself. Surprised this wasn't supported, i ended up having to store status in logfiles etc.

Comment: That sucks, I have not been able to do this either! Thanks!